# Installing Python 2.7 and 3.6 Side by Side on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

Python newbie here. I just bought a new Mac Book Pro (switched from Windows) and Python 2.7 is already installed on it. I want to install 3.6 side by side and choose between the two versions. I found a great tutorial located here http://joebergantine.com/articles/installing-python-2-and-python-3-alongside-each-ot/ but I'm confused on one of the command line operations. Under Python 2 Installation it says:

Install Python 2 from the latest Python.org package. This allows you to run python2 and pip. After this installation Python 2.x will be accessible at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/.

> Once the Python 2 package is installed, install virtualenv for Python
>   2 for the User only. When specifying the User installation, Python
>   packages are then accessible at ~/Library/Python/2.7/bin. Specifying
>   the User installation doesn't automatically add virtualenv to the
>   system path which we will do manually in the next step via an alias.
>   This is what allows Python3 and Python2 to run alongside each other:

```
$ pip install --user virtualenv
```

Do I have to be in the ~/Library/Python/2.7/bin directory when I run this command or the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ directory? I'm confused because I don't know where the former directory is coming from.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use Homebrew, and install Python versions side by side. These are normally installed in `/usr/local/`, so you can adjust your PATH, but you can always access the individual Python versions by using `python2.7` and `python3.6` explicitly.

Comment: As to your current setup, you probably should add `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin` to your PATH variable. Alternatively, you should be in that directory, and execute the relevant `pip` command with `./pip`, so you are sure not some other `pip` command will be executed.

Comment: If found the article [Hacker Codex - Python Development Environment on macOS Sierra and El Capitan](https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) to be a very good guide in setting up your Python environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using `pip` for `python 2.7` and `pip3` for `python 3.6`?

If it says pip3 is not installed you can use `sudo apt-get install pip3`

then you can use pip3 for python 3.6 and pip for python2.7 for installing packages for respective versions

Comment: I'm not that familiar with pip but your solution sounds ideal. Can you elaborate? Do I have to install Python 3 after pip?

Comment: bro as you said you have 2 versions of python, so for this type of systems pip and pip3 is available. pip for python2 and pip3 for python3. so if you want to install any package for python2 you can install them with pip and same for python3 use pip3.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact error, in the exact situation about 2 years ago. The solution to your issue is [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). I was able to run multiple versions of python inside different folders of the same directory. It truly was a very nice solution.
Hope this helps.